# Better ways to check to see if Datetime has special character

Tags: c#, datetime

One of the parameters in my get method is a datetime like below:

```
 http://localhost/accounts/?name=Junetest&uid=00000002&datetimechange=2015-04-12 15:14:20-0500
```

Inside my controller, I convert the datetime ie.

```
 if (row["datetimechange"] != null){
     var dtNewValue = Convert.ToDateTime(row["datetimechange"].ToString());
    }
```

This works if the value passed is correct. However, if I add some special characters

```
 http://localhost/accounts/?name=Junetest&uid=00000002&datetimechange=2015-      04-12 15:14:20-0500asfdsfsdfds
```

the conversion still does not throw any exception and it fails only when during the actual get operation.

Is there a way to check to see if the datetime has no special characters or extra characters and then throw an exception during conversion and not after the conversion.

I thought of using regular expression or tryParse. Am I thinking correctly? Pls. let me know if there is more cleaner way to handle this

Comment: Eh, `DateTime.TryParseExact()`?

Comment: do you mean sometimes even with wrong input converting success and you want to throw exception?

Comment: Kazem, Yes, even with extra characters at the end is converting success but I would like to throw an exception.

Comment: the best way is regex. ugliest way is to check if string contains double space and last char of string is not digit!

Comment: Dmitry, I tried DateTime.Tryparse(). Still the same behavior. It parses sucessfully,

Comment: Dmitry, I tried         var dtNewValue = DateTime.Parse(row["datetimechange"].ToString());                                                still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Better try filtering using regex

```
if (row["datetimechange"] != null){
string temp=Convert.ToDateTime(row["datetimechange"].ToString());
MatchCollection mc1 = Regex.Matches(temp, @"[^a-zA-Z]");
foreach (Match m in mc)
                dtNewValue=dtNewValue+m.Value.ToString()
}
```

You can add more filtering to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx)

Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified array of formats, culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the string representation must match at least one of the specified formats exactly. The method returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or MinValue if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if s or formats is null, s or an element of formats is an empty string, or the format of s is not exactly as specified by at least one of the format patterns in formats.

`var x = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue);`